# Using GLUT in FLTK

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut, fltk

My application consists of regular FLTK widgets (buttons, etc.), and an OpenGL window. My intention is to use GLUT to draw in this OpenGL Window. As per instructions [here](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/glut.html):

> You should be able to compile existing GLUT source code by including
>    instead of . This can be done by editing the
>   source, by changing the -I switches to the compiler, or by providing a
>   symbolic link from GL/glut.h to FL/glut.H.

I have done the same but I get the following linking errors:

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glFlush@0
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glFlush@0
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glReadBuffer@4
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawBuffer@4
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glOrtho@48
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glViewport@16
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetIntegerv@8
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglSwapLayerBuffers@8
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glCopyPixels@20
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glRasterPos2i@8
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glRasterPos2i@8
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDisable@4
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglRealizeLayerPalette@12
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglShareLists@8
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglCreateContext@4
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglCreateLayerContext@8
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglMakeCurrent@8
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglDeleteContext@4
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Device_Plugin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glPopClientAttrib@0
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Device_Plugin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glReadPixels@28
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Device_Plugin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glPixelStorei@8
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glPixelStorei@8
1>fltkgl.lib(Fl_Gl_Device_Plugin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glPushClientAttrib@4
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glListBase@4
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGenLists@4
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDeleteLists@8
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glCallLists@12
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglUseFontBitmapsW@16
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glRasterPos2f@8
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnd@0
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glVertex2i@8
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBegin@4
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor3ub@12
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glIndexi@4
1>fltkgl.lib(gl_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawPixels@20
1>D:\Skunkworks\Snake3D\Snake3D\Release\Snake3D.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 35 unresolved externals
```

The program was compiling properly when I was using FreeGLUT. After changing headers to use FLTK's version of GLUT I am getting these problems. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 10 and have added the following static libraries as 'Additional Depedencies':

> freeglut.lib glew32.lib fltk.lib fltkgl.lib

What am I doing wrong? Also, how do I draw in my Fl_Gl_Window using GLUT?

Here is my program:

```
// Make the GUI here
#define WIN32
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <FL/glut.H>
#include <FL/glu.h>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Color_Chooser.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Gl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Menu_Bar.H>
#include <FL/fl_draw.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>

class Block
{
public:
    Block(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        xyz[0] = x;
        xyz[1] = y;
        xyz[2] = z;
    }

    int getX(){ return xyz[0];}
    int getY(){ return xyz[1];}
    int getZ(){ return xyz[2];}

    void setX(int x){ xyz[0]=x;}
    void setY(int y){ xyz[1]=y;}
    void setZ(int z){ xyz[2]=z;}

private:
    int xyz[3];
};

// Snake is an array blocks.
Block* snake;
// Mouse is a single block
Block* mouse;

class GlWindow : public Fl_Gl_Window
{
public:
    // Call back for draw
    void draw()
    {
        // Get the current state of the universe and draw it
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Clear the background of our window to red  
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Clear the colour buffer (more buffers later on)  
        glLoadIdentity(); // Load the Identity Matrix to reset our drawing locations  

        //glutSolidCube(5);
        glFlush(); // Flush the OpenGL buffers to the window  
    }

    // To handle key-events
    void handle()
    {
    }

    // Constructor
    GlWindow(int X, int Y, int W, int H, const char* L=0): Fl_Gl_Window(X,Y,W,H,L)
    {
    }

};

void buildGUI(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Main Window  
    Fl_Double_Window *window = new Fl_Double_Window(800,500);
    window->label("Snake3D");
    window->color(FL_LIGHT3);
    window->begin();

    // Menu Bar
    Fl_Menu_Bar* menubar = new Fl_Menu_Bar(0,0,800,30);
    menubar->color(FL_LIGHT3);
    menubar->down_color(fl_rgb_color(0,145,255));
    menubar->box(FL_THIN_UP_BOX);
    menubar->add("File/Exit");
    menubar->add("Help/About");

    // OpenGL Window
    GlWindow* gameWindow = new GlWindow(200,30,600,470);

    // Start Button
    Fl_Button* startButton = new Fl_Button(50,200,100,30,"Start");
    Fl_Button* pauseButton = new Fl_Button(50,300,100,30,"Pause");
    window->show();
    window->end();
    Fl::run();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{   
    // Build GUI
    buildGUI(argc,argv);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### This has nothing to do with GLUT.

All of those functions are part of OpenGL 1.1 and the Windows-specific window system API (WGL).

To fix this, just add `opengl32.lib` to your libraries.

Almost every one of those functions is deprecated, however, and you might consider looking for a modern alternative to FLTKGL if portability is a concern.